# singleton create new window

Tags: java, javafx-2

It's good practice to use singleton to create new window?

I have main window and i want create another one. This window will be used only to change  properties in main window.

My code:

Main Window

```
public class MainWindow  {

private StackPane root = new StackPane();
private Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

  public void run(){

    primaryStage.setTitle("v0.2-alpha");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().addAll("css/style.css"); 

    MainMenu mmb = new MainMenu();     

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().add(mmb.createMenuBar());

    ISplitPane lsp = new SplitPaneLeftImpl();
    ISplitPane csp = new SplitPaneCenterImpl();
    ISplitPane rsp = new SplitPaneRightImpl();

   HBox hboxpane = new HBox();
   hboxpane.getChildren().addAll(spl.createSplitPane(), spc.createSplitPane(), spr.createSplitPane());

    root.getChildren().addAll(vBox,hboxpane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}

Create new window class

```
public interface IStage {
    public void createStage();
}



class StageOptionsImpl implements IStage{
private OptionsStage(){}

private Stage stageOptions = new Stage();

private static StageOptionsImpl os = null;

public static StageOptionsImpl getInstance(){
    if(os == null){
        synchronized(StageOptionsImpl.class){
            if(os == null){
                os = new StageOptionsImpl();
            }
        }
    }
    return os;
}

@Override
public void createStage(){
 GridPane gp  = new GridPane();
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);                

    Tab tabSecurity = new Tab("Security");
    tabSecurity.setContent(new SecurityTab().tabCreate());

    Tab tab2 = new Tab("System Data");
    tab2.setContent(new DataTab().tabCreate());

    Tab tab3 = new Tab("tab 3");
    tab3.setContent(new SecurityTab().tabCreate());

    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tabSecurity, tab2, tab3);

    Scene sceneOptions = new Scene(tabPane, 400, 300, Color.AQUA);
    stageOptions.setScene(sceneOptions);
    stageOptions.show();
}
}
```

Comment: "Singleton" shouldn't be in any "best practice" unless preceded by "don't".

Answer (score 1):

If it's only used from there, why would you want a singleton. Whole point of a Singleton is so you can use the same intance of it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> It's good practice to use singleton to create new window?

Well, that comes down to a design question.

If you only ever want to have a single, shared instance of a `Component` in you're application, then I would say a singlton is not a bad approach.  It will force this choice.

If, however, you want to display multiple instances of the same `Component` but want, say, a simpler way to construct it, or want to expose a non-concrete interface through the API, then a `Factory` pattern would be of a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to manage these windows is usually by creating a class that manages all of the windows/panels in the program.

If you wanted to open the panel called 'ClientForm' it should have a method like this:

```
public void OpenClientForm(){

// Set the other forms to their default form(when != null) and set their visibility as false (when != null).
    RestorePanels();
 // In case it hasn't been created yet 
 if (ClientForm == null){
 // calls a factory that creates the form.
 }
 else{
 // Set the form as visible
 }
}
```

When 'disposing' of panels/forms inside of the program you should have a method that clears the panels, forcing them back to their original state and setting their visible as false.

Swing is pretty buggy, disposing of the forms and recreating them could mess up a lot of things in your interface. So, back to your question... implemeting a singleton or a factory to manage ur forms should be the best approach.
Hope this helps.